# Postgresql character in Numeric (12,2) type

Tags: database, postgresql, types, numeric

i have some trouble with my database,

i found a value '=0267000.00' in a numeric type

how is this possible? and how postgresql accepted that '=' in a numeric type?

i found this strange, it's cause also some problems in restoring the database.

best regards,

Comment: Postgres does not accept `=` in numeric type. Are you sure that `'=0267000.00'` was in numeric field?

Comment: i know that it's not possible and that make me crazy
http://postimg.org/image/q5y5h26sn/

Comment: i just found this error when i wanted to restore a dump file, 
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] COPY failed: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "=0267000.00"
and when i checked the db i found this horrible things :/

Comment: Maybe the column type changed (from `text` to `numeric`) and you are trying to restore a dump with old column type to a DB with new column type?

Comment: Hm. Can you try to execute your query with `psql`? To be sure that it is not a bug of client software. Also what is the version of Postgres ?

Comment: hi, http://postimg.org/image/bwlm98oyz/

Comment: It looks like a bug. Try updating your postgres version. If it does not help - try writing about it in postgres mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like the type is of type text and is being cast to numeric somewhere.

The bad news is there isn't a really safe way to sanitize the data without looking at the sorts of errors you have.  Once you can have a selection of your errors then you can look at how to sanitize your data and ensure that the data is correct going forwards.

A second possibility, if you can show that it is a numeric type is you could have a locale bug in your system libraries this could be a similar problem.  However I dont think that lc_numeric is commonly used for number formatting in my experience, but it is possible that I am wrong on that.  At any rate if it is a numeric field in the db (as shown by \d) I would certainly file a bug report about it.  Valid output usually should be valid input (though there are a few exceptions to this in PostgreSQL).